# If error then skip sending an email

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have a piece of code that sends me an email when a button is pressed.
However if for some reason the email won't send I don't want the code to break, I would like it to just ignore this command and carry on.  How do I add that into my current code?

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = ThisWorkbook.Name & vbNewLine & _
          Environ("username")
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "bm@Email.co.uk"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "OGI Statements Used"
    .Body = strbody
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Thank you

Comment: I see the On Error Resume Next already in your code. Is an error being raised on the .Send line even with your this in place?

Comment: The trouble is I don't know because it works on my machine.  The macro will be used on a number of different versions of systems, so I want to make as sure as I can that the debug error won't pop up if there is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your error statement to avoid the `.Send` method in the case of an *earlier* error - but if the error occurs with the actual sending of the email then there's not a lot you can do as the execution has been handed over to another application and so it's out of the error handler's scope so to speak.

See if this is of any use:

```
On Error GoTo Skip:
With OutMail
    .To = "bm@Email.co.uk"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "OGI Statements Used"
    .Body = strbody
    .Send
End With
Skip:
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: When I do this the email doesn't seem to send at all :(

Comment: Then there is an error somewhere in your code before the `.Send` command - I would start by [debugging your code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Must have typed it in wrong, works now.  Now I just hope it works.  Thank you for such a speedy response!